# Logstash Grok Modifying and overwriting @timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok

My logs having timestamps in format of: Nov 19 00:06:37

I need to have this format to be converted to ISO 8601 timestamp and used as @timestamp field?

What would be the correct configuration to handle this? I have the following config right now:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:logTimestamp} %{USERNAME:myServer} %{USERNAME:myProcessName}: %{INT:operationType} %{WORD}, \"%{INT} %{WORD}, %{WORD} %{WORD}: /%{WORD}/%{WORD:clientId}/%{WORD}, %{WORD} %{WORD}: %{WORD:myId1}, \"%{WORD:status}\", %{WORD}-%{WORD}: %{INT:sessionId}" 
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "logTimestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it give you if you try it out? On my end, I correctly get a timestamp value `"@timestamp" => "2015-11-18T23:06:37.000Z"` which is the ISO8601 equivalent of your syslog date.

Comment: Right now all the @timestamp values are the timestamp when the log is processed and not the ones from the log files. As example if I'm processing logs from yesterday I'm getting Today's timestamp in the elastic search.

Comment: Do you see a `_grokparsefailure` in the `tags`field of your log events in ES?

Answer (score 4):

To update the value of @timestamp generated by Logstash as a metadata parameter, to the value timestamp or logTimestamp generated by grok, use date plugin to match and update the value of @timestamp.

```
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }  # --> COMBINEDAPACHELOG gives timestamp as output
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"]  #  --> Here match the pattern of timestamp to the format
      target => "@timestamp"    # --> Here the @timestamp value will be updated
      remove_field => ["timestamp"]
    }
    useragent {
      source => "agent"
    }
  }
```

Reference:
date plugin - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target